# how can i get the data from a view which is in json array

Tags: mysql

I created a view using JSON array but I did not get the data from that view by giving where condition.and if I create in JSON object I'm getting it but not in JSON array

I'm tried json_extract

```
select * from vw_json where json_extract(a,"$[*].empname")='jimmy';
```

a is my column name and jimmy is my value. When I try this showing 0 rows

```
create view vw_json as  select concat(json_array ('eid',id,'empname',ename)) as a,
concat(json_array('esal',sal,'edeptno',deptno))as emp from employe;
```

this is my view 
and

```
select * from vw_json where json_extract(a,"$[*].empname")='jimmy';
```

this is I'm trying

the expected output is

```
{"eid": 2, "empname": "jimmy"}, {"esal": "3000", "edeptno": "3"}
```

Comment: You would provide source data

Comment: I'm tried but where to mention i don"t know

Comment: ["eid", 1, "empname", "john"], ["esal", "2000", "edeptno", "2"]      
                ["eid", 2, "empname", "jimmy"], ["esal", "3000", "edeptno", "3"]